# Configuração CNAME para serviço SaaS

Tags: configuração, saas

Ok, eu sei que para configurar um CNAME eu vou até o editor de DNS simples e crio a seguinte configuração.

servico.meudominio.com. CNAME username.servico.com

Irei manter o serviço em um subdminio conforme o primeiro endereço acima, a dúvida é o outro endereço servico.com é um domínio meu também onde pretendo colocar um serviço SaaS, a minha dúvida é: O que eu preciso fazer para neste domínio servico.com para que meus cliente possam configurar a CNAME na hospedagem deles e o serviço funcionar sob o domínio configurado?

Agradeço quem puder ajudar pois já faz 1 semana que estou pesquisando sobre o assunto e até então só encontro posts sobre como configurar a CNAME e como já faz 2 dias que fiz a configuração e o domínio ainda não esta acessível, gostaria de saber se há algo que eu preciso fazer em servico.com

Abraços!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um CNAME é como se fosse um apelido, então com base no seu exemplo, digitar `servico.meudominio.com` vai resolver para o IP do subdomínio `username.servico.com`, ou seja o subdomínio `username` em `servico.com` deve responder por um IP.

Você deve criar cada subdomínio na tabela DNS ou uma zona wildcard (*).

**ZONA DNS em meudominio.com**

```
servico 14400 IN CNAME username.servico.com.
```

**ZONA DNS em servico.com**

```
username 14400 IN CNAME servico.com.

ou

* 14400 IN CNAME servico.com.
```

Para obter o dominio que originou a requisição, em PHP você pode usar a variável `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` vai resultar: `'servico.meudominio.com'`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @jader, vou testar aqui e te falo o resultado.

Comment: Não deu certo =/

Atualmente minhas configurações estão assim:

**Meu Domínio**
`servico.meusite.com. 14400 IN CNAME username.servico.com`

**Zona DNS em servico.com**
`username.servico.com. 14400 IN A ip-do-site-do-servico`

Pelo o que eu entendi em meu domínio, uso o CNAME para apontar para o meu usuário no serviço e o serviço, aponta para o endereço de IP onde esta configurado as DNS, sendo assim `servico.meudominio.com` deveria funcionar correto?

Acredito que as configurações CNAME em `meudomonio.com` estão ok, mas falta algo em `servico.com`, alguma sugestão?

Comment: @fabiogoodoy e quando você digita diretamente username.servico.com funciona? Não me refiro apenas ao ping, mas se funciona o serviço de fato como deveria...

Comment: Sim, @jader o endereço do serviço é esse: (http://demo.eadplataforma.com) que é um site meu também, e aí queria que ele funcionasse no endereço de teste que é esse (http://ead.fabiogodoy.org) então fiz as configurações conforme todos os posts que encontrei e conforme você recomendou, mas realmente não funcionou. =/ no endereço (http://eadplataforma.com) inclusive tenho o Google Apps que funciona desta forma usando CNAME.

Comment: @fabiogoodoy Me parece que o virtualhost no servidor http é específico para aquele subdomínio, por isso não esta aceitando o CNAME vindo do outro domínio... Adicionar o domínio como estacionado, ou configurar diretamente no virtualhost como serveralias pode resolver...

Comment: @fabiogoodoy em tempo, antes de acionar a resposta, fiz testes, com domínios hospedados em servidores dedicados separados, mas nos meus testes o domínio de destino aceitava subdomínios como wildcard, e recebeu o domínio externo sem nenhum problema, mas testando com um domínio sem wildcard e sem o subdomínio configurado não funcionou, nem resolveu o IP... veja mais sobre servername e serveralias nesse [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/417810/difference-between-servername-and-serveralias)

Comment: Obrigado @Jader, irei fazer testes aqui e ler um pouco mais sobre server alias para ver se resolve.